# How to check if more than one checkbox is checked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I check if more than one checkbox is checked in my controller?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKVH6/506/)

My markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <label>{{item.Name}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
    </label>
</li>
```

My Code:

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    //i want to check if checkbox checked more than 1
    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bound the checkbox state for each item to `item.Selected`, so if checkbox is selected for an item, `item.Selected` should be true.

You just have to count items where the `Selected` attribute is set to true.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <label>{{item.Name}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
    </label>
</li>

// Returns the count of selected items
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    var count = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        if (item.Selected) count++;
    });

    return count;
};
```

Comment: It's not working because `checkAll` is never called... :)
Look here http://jsfiddle.net/p7kmxa8x/